# if you want all css properties as a type in typescript what do you put?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

StyleProps is used for size and colour.

I would prefer it was all styles.

This is so I can hand down the styles directly into the specific part of the component.

what do I put in to mean the types of all CSS properties?

how do I change the styles to be all styles?

```
interface StyleProps{
  color?: string;
  size?: string;
}

interface TextButtonProps {
  buttonStyle?: styleProps;
  click: () => void;
  text: string;
}

const TextButton = ({ buttonStyle, text, click }: TextButtonProps) => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the built-in type `CSSStyleDeclaration` (ES6 lib typings):

```
interface StyleProps extends Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration> {
  color?: string; // ! not necessary
  size?: string;
}

interface TextButtonProps {
  buttonStyle?: StyleProps;
  click: () => void;
  text: string;
}

const TextButton = ({ buttonStyle, text, click }: TextButtonProps) => {
```

`Partial` is used because the built-in type's properties are all required.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgJ4BsIAUoD2ADgM7IQAekIAJmbnFGMHFgDwDCq3mOAIhARZGcZgRAA+ZAG8AsAChkyBASwEoAfgBcyEmCigA5gG5kAejPIAhMhAEwtwRBIlGGBUpLAAXhG279I2MFAF8FBVBIWEQUABVKMAAhAFcwMHF8YjI5RWQAI1T0kHRsPx0SnEzSYNyhYAQAax0ACgBKZABeKQA3AmAaGqVIKh09AxATUPD5FRA9ZHiqFLTxTuRm6XzC8QqIABpkYbADusbkEJ1FpO2QKpJ2rplQoA)

Answer (score 0):

**How to extend intrinsic element properties**

Example: Native

```
interface IButton extends ClassAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  // custom properties
  size: ESize;
  variant: EVariant;
}
```

Example: React.js

```
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface IButton extends ButtonHtmlAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  // custom properties
  size: ESize;
  variant : EVariant;
}
```

...

BTW The `ESize` and `EVariant` are [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)'s, not relevant to understand the examples.